# Remove q=/search? from Query String in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using OctoberCMS based on Laravel.

I'm trying to get the query string so I can parse it into variables.

It's putting q=/search? before the string and it won't parse.

It needs to be only what's after the question mark.

**Page:**

```
localhost:8888/search
```

**Query:**

```
localhost:8888/search?tags=galaxy
```

**Results:**

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

null
```

or

```
$queryString = getenv('QUERY_STRING');

q=/search?tags=galaxy
```

or

```
$queryString = \Request:getQueryString();

q=%2Fsearch%3Ftags%3Dgalaxy
```

**Parse:**

```
$tags = ''; 
parse_str($queryString);
echo $tags;
```

**Solutions?**

I tried using explode() on the "?" but I get an error when there is no query present. Undefined offset: 1.

Comment: Try using `explode()` inside an `if` checking if there is any query present (i.e: `if (isset($queryString))` or `if (!empty($queryString))`

Comment: Where are you trying to get this query string? If you're in a controller, you should be able to use `Request::input()` to get the parameters passed via the query string. I feel like you *shouldn't* have to do manual manipulation on the query string like this... That being said, I'm not familiar with OctoberCMS, so maybe you do.

Comment: @Condorcho Unfortunately when it grabs and empty query, it still gets "q=/search" without any parameters, and is not empty.

Comment: @TimLewis I'm doing it inside a model. It's just a simple seach engine I made that grabs the query made from an html5 search input box and, parses it into variables and uses them in a scope to filter results.